# Do I have a FUSE-enabled kernel?

Tags: kernel

I would like toknow if my kernel supports FUSE. If not, how do I build or download one with FUSE support, where on the FS do I place the kernel? I don't want to install CyanogenMod. I have a Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo, KitKat 4.4.2. Thanks.

Comment: With Kitkat, your device most likely uses FUSE for the internal SD card already. You could check that utilizing the `df` and `mount` commands (via terminal or `adb shell`). A good hint that it does is the same size of available space being reported for `/data` and the SD card (usually `/storage/sdcard0`).

Comment: @Izzy culd you please provide more detail in an answer. There should be a specific command (maybe even an app)other than checking file sizes. Thanks.

Comment: I have no device to cross-check this with, so I cannot provide detailed instructions (as I could not verify them) – my devices use separate partitions for the SD card and thus don't mount it via FUSE. Check the output of `mount | grep sdcard`, the mount options should tell something. // Apart from which: If I'm not taken wrong, MTP uses FUSE as well; see e.g. [Why does Android use fuse for internal SD card mount?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/50056/16575)